# set width for the div containing elements displayed as table to fit content

Tags: html, css

How can I set the width for the `div` that contains `p` elements displayed as tables to fit the content? [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jBp7L/)
HTML:

```
<div>
    <p>
        <span>text1</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span>text2</span>
    </p>
<div>
```

CSS:

```
p {
    display:table;
    background-color:red;
}

span {
    display:table-cell;
    width: 100px;
}

div {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: set the width of div to 100px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `display:table` for the div as well will make it adjust for the width:

```
div {
    background-color: green;
    display:table;
}
```

Edit: As pointed out in the comments `display:inline-block` will also do the job, depending on exactly how you want this div to behave.

Answer (score 1):

First of all `remove width attribute` from span give `inline-block` to div

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jBp7L/5/)

Final css would be

```
p {
    display:table;
    background-color:red;
}

span {
    display:table-cell;
}

div {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to shrink wrap the div content, add `float:left` to the div:

```
div {
    background-color: green;
    float:left;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jBp7L/4/)**

Comment: `float` is the wrong tool for this job -- `display:table` or `display:inline-block` will collapse the node's width without the unintended side effects that `float` is likely to cause.

Comment: @DanielBeck - What "side effects" are likely to be caused?

Comment: Seriously?   Well, the div will be floating to the left, for starters.  Unnecessary floats are likely to interfere with the surrounding layout, or require additional markup to work around them.

Comment: @DanielBeck - Do I look like I'm joking? Of course seriously. What about a float is a "side effect" that if anything, a clear can't fix?

Comment: A clear is exactly the sort of thing I mean by unnecessary additional markup.